# Prove the required form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

Let $a$ and $b$ be coprime integers and $(x_0, y_0)$ be a set of integer solutions of the Diophantine equation $ax+by=1$. Prove that any set of integer solution is of the form $x = x_0 + bt$, 
$y = y_0 - at$, where $t\in\Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hint: Look at Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: @user122049 I looked, but I can't proceed. Please help

Comment: @user122049 The Euclidean algorithm is needed to *solve* the equation, but this is not needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a$ and $b$ are both nonzero.

Consider $G=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:ax+by=0\}$. This is clearly a proper and nontrivial subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, so it is generated by a single element, namely $(b,-a)$.

However, the general theorem can be avoided in this simple case. Indeed, if $ax+by=0$, then
$$
ax=-by
$$
so $a\mid by$ and, since $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we get $a\mid y$. Therefore $y=as$. Similarly, $x=bt$. Now $abt+abs=0$ implies $s=-t$, so
$$
(x,y)=(bt,-at)=t(b,-a)
$$
Conversely, any element of the form $t(b,-a)=(tb,-ta)$ is a solution.

Suppose $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$ are solutions of $ax+by=1$. Then $(x_1-x_0,y_1-y_0)$ is a solution of $ax+by=0$, so
$$
(x_1,y_1)=(x_0,y_0)+t(b,-a)
$$
and, conversely, any pair of this kind is a solution of $ax+by=1$. Therefore *all* solutions of $ax+by=1$ are of the form
$$
x=x_0+tb,\qquad y=y_0-at
$$

Suppose $b=0$, so $a=\pm1$. For $a=1$, the solutions of $ax+0y=1$ are of the form $x=1+0t$, $y=0-1t$. Similarly if $a=-1$.

*How* to find a particular solution $(x_0,y_0)$ is another matter.

Comment: yes it's another thing to deal with

Answer (score 1):

We assume there is a solution $x,$ $y$ with $ax+by=1.$ We define $t=\frac{x-x_0}{b}$ (not necessarily integer), which is equivalent with $t=\frac{y_0-y}{a}.$ We have $bt=x-x_0$ and $at=y_0-y.$

Then $t = (ax_0+by_0)\,t = at\,x_0+bt\,y_0 = (y_0-y)x_0 + (x-x_0)y_0 = xy_0-yx_0 \in\mathbb{Z},$ and we obtain $x=x_0+bt$ and $y=y_0-at$ with $t\in\mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: Dissatisfied with your answer. Where did you took coprime into consideration?

Comment: @ChenGuo You need the property of $a$ and $b$ being coprime only for stating the problem (you wouldn't be able to achieve $ax+by=1$ or $ax_0+by_0=1$ if $a$ and $b$ weren't coprime, because $ax+by$ and $ax_0+by_0$ are obviously divisible by each common divisor of $a$ and $b$.) But you do not need the property for the actual proof. By the way, *not* using each and every premise does not necessarily make a proof invalid.

Comment: Look at egreg's solve. How to find particular solution pair (x0,y0)

Comment: Is this a question? Do you want to know how to find $(x_0,y_0)$? egreg does not answer this, either.

Comment: sorry friend but egreg gave me a better idea, yours proof seems to be meaningless

Comment: No problem. I must admit that egreg's proof gives a better insight into the underlying theory. By the way, if you want to know how to get $(x_0,y_0)$, I recommend to take a look at [Extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm)

Comment: Thanks Friend. I am grateful

Answer (score 1):

Subtract $ax_0+by_0=1$ from $ax+by=1$ ?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   ax + by &=1 \\
   ax_0 + by_0 &= 1 \\
\hline
   a(x-x_0) + b(y-y_0) &= 0 \\
   b(y-y_0) &= -a(x-x_0) \tag{1.}
\end{align}

Since $a$ and $b$ are coprime, then there exists integers $A$ and $B$ such that $aA +bB = 1$. Hence
\begin{align}
   aA +bB &= 1 \\
   a(y-y_0)A + b(y-y_0)B &= (y-y_0) \\
   a(y-y_0)A - a(x-x_0)B &= (y-y_0) &\text{(Using (1.))} \tag{2.}\\
\end{align}

Clearly $a$ divides the left side of equation $(2.)$. Hence $a$ divides $y-y_0$, say

$$y-y_0 = at \tag{3.}$$

for some integer $t$.  Substituting this back into equation $(1.)$, we get
$bat = -a(x-x_0)$. Dividing both sides by $a$, we get

$$x-x_0 = -bt \tag{4.}$$

Solving equations $(3.)$ and $(4.)$ for $x$ and $y$, we find that, for some integer t, $$ x=x_0-bt \quad \text{and} \quad y=y_0+bt$$

It works the other way too. 
$ax + by = a(x_0 - bt) + b(y_0 + bt) = ax_0 + by_0 = 1$

So $(x,y)$ is a solution to $ax+by=1$ if and only if for some integer $t$,
$ x=x_0-bt \quad \text{and} \quad y=y_0+bt$.

Comment: I already accepted the answer above...I posted this question long before....

Comment: what exactly do you want to say?

Comment: I want to say this is how I would do it

Comment: I can't ignore egreg's answer.....and moreover I am having new questions to be discussed here....This question is already old....I am sorry I cannot accept your answer

Comment: You don't have to do anything. Just let it be.

Comment: hope you didn't misunderstand me

Comment: This website is about mathematics, not points, not doing someones homework. I like getting points. I love mathematics. You don't need to explain anything.

Comment: please don't mind anything